# add indent to "@RenderBody()"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there any way to add indent in `_layout.cshtml` side in `@RenderBody()` to make source code beautiful?

The problem is adding indent in `_layout.cshtml` page before `@RenderBody()` is not working. I must add indent in my View like (`index.cshtml`), and I want to move that to "_layout.cshtml"

**_layout.cshtml:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         @RenderBody()
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TestLayout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
```

**Page view-source:**

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div>
<h2>Index</h2> <!-- problem here -->
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

my solution is add indent to **index.cshtml** like this code:

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TestLayout.cshtml";
}
*************<h2>Index</h2><!-- my solution -->
```

is there any way to move that to **_layout.cshtml:** ?

Comment: Why you need indents? All modern browsers will indent your html for your.

Comment: @teovankot I use razor templates for code generation, not HTML(outside of ASP.NET). It would be nice to have this feature.

Comment: @Konrad maybe it's better just find appropriate tool for your particular case instead of trying to create swiss knife out of Razor.

Comment: @teovankot well, works nice for me. And Microsoft uses it too for generating C# code in their autorest tool

Comment: It's definitely better than T4 templates.

Comment: https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight

Comment: It's just a template engine, I can use it for anything

Comment: @Konrad no doubt you can. I'm just not sure how important to fix this indent bug. Still, they have an open issue for something similar. https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1076
Maby this repo is the right place to report a bug that OP found.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do so with APS.NET xxx render engine.

Nevertheless, here is my solution pending a better solution.

You can write your **index.cshtml** like this:

**My newest version** - better and cleaner (**edited in october 2023**)

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TestLayout.cshtml";
}

@{
    {
        {
            <h2>Index</h2>
        }
    }
}
```

The Razor Code above is pretty clean and you would have this in your **Page view-source**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Index</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my code above with a better solution